# Add up numbers in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, addition

I got a very simple problem that I cant figure out.

This is what i want to do :

```
6 * (1/(1*1) + 1/(2*2) + 1/(3*3) + … + 1/(N*N))
```

And this is my code attempt, that does not work.

```
int eingabe = 5;
double c = 0;

    for (int i = 1 ; i<=eingabe ;i++) {
         c += 1/(i*i);
    }
    c *= 6;
    System.out.println(c);
```

Please help me guys ! What do I have to do to make the code work?

Comment: who needs loops? `return (n * (n+1) / 2);`

Comment: @RossDrew It's not arithmetic progression in this question

Comment: I know @rtruszk - that's why it was a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `1/(i*i)` to `1.0/(i*i)`, currently you're doing integer division

Answer (score 2):

```
int eingabe = 5;
double c = 0;

for (int i = 1 ; i<=eingabe ;i++) {
     c += 1.0/(double)(i*i);
}
c *= 6;
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: casting to (double) is not needed here. When you divide double number by integer number then integer will be automatically converted to double

Comment: and you don't need 1.0 .  1 is sufficient if u cast